# Dependent HTTP calls in angular service

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient

I am calling secured REST API's from angular service. In this case I have to get token once before calling any API as pass it as a part of HTTP Header. But when ever I am calling any function from my component I am getting app_token as undefined. This is due to async call to token_api. Next call gets successes as earlier call fetches value for token from server.

I have added async-await to get_token function, but in vain..
Any advice on how to handle this situation.

```
private app_token;

private getToken(){    
    if (this.token == undefined) {
      console.log("getting new token");
      return this.httpClient.post<Token>(this.TOKEN_API, body, options)
        .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError))
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data[0].username);
            return this.app_token = data;
        });
    }
}

public getEmployee{
    this.getToken();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.app_token );

    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };

    return this.httpClient.get(this.EMP_API, options)
      .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
}

public getDepartments{
    this.getToken();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.app_token );

    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };

    return this.httpClient.get(this.DEPT_API, options)
      .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution for this issue.  Here I am using RxJS Pipe and concatMap functions to execute 2 http request and passing output of one request to other.

```
  return this.getToken().pipe(
    concatMap((tokenData)=> {
      headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token.access_token);

      return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: headers })
        .pipe( retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert observable into promise from the `getToken()` using `toPromise()`:

```
private getToken(){    
    if (this.token == undefined) {
      console.log("getting new token");
      return this.httpClient.post<Token>(this.TOKEN_API, body, options)
        .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError))
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data[0].username);
            return this.app_token = data;
        })
        .toPromise();
    }
}
```

Now you can easily use async/await for this function

```
public async getEmployee{
    await this.getToken();

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.app_token );

    const options = {
      headers: headers
    };

    return this.httpClient.get(this.EMP_API, options)
      .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Note: Please handle the error if `getToken()` fails to retrieve a token.

Comment: 1) They have already done `subscribe` on the observable, so it's a subscription, not an observable. You can't do toPromise on a subscription. 2) Why converting an observable to a promise anyways? Observables are more powerful than promises

Comment: There's no doubt Observables are more powerful than Promises. But after working a lot with Promise, and the syntactic sugar of "async/await", I wonder if it was a wise decision of the Angular team to drop Promises in favor of Observables. Well-designed code using async-await is a lot easier to maintain. So I'm upvoting the answer again. The idea is good, although I have to admit the execution is probably poor. Combining `subscribe()` and `toPromise()` looks like a bad idea to me.